# When will linux close a fd except I call 'close'?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, pipe

When will linux close a fd except I call 'close'?

The fd may be a socket, a pipe, a file, or anything else.

I know it will be closed when:

1. I call 'close' function directly or indirectly (e.g. fclose(FILE*)).
2. The program is forked (as child) and the fd has a CLOEXEC flag.
3. The program is crashed or exited.

Is there any way else that makes a fd closed?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why? Is this a practical problem you've run into?

Comment: I expect that a *hot* unplug of an usb device will cause this as well

Comment: When you shutdown your computer... ;)

Comment: Wrong formulation for case 2: `CLOEXEC` works on `execve`, not at `fork` time!

Comment: @hek2mgl No, no more than smashing your harddrive with a hammer will close the fd associated with it.

Comment: Yes, unplug will render the fd useless, but not close it from the applications standpoint - it will return some error if you try to do something with it (possibly even on close). I take it the purpose of the original question is either a interview or school test question.

Comment: @JimBalter Was too lazy to write a test program. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I should read more kernel codes :)